# Anti file deletion for multiplatform (Windows, Linux and OSX); is it possible?

Tags: c

I'm developing some software for data encryption in C. Here, I just want to ask whether there are any possibilities to make use of some techniques for anti data deletion "without relying much on specific OS API"? If your answer is that it *is* possible, I would be happy if you can to tell how and give me a lot of explanation. Otherwise, if it is impossible, you can give me the answer "It is impossible" without much explanation.

The reason why I do to ask is that, I anticipate if someday the attacker had already physical access   to the machine, the anti-deletion by using dependent OS API will not work (for example, by using a very fast booting OS like Backtrack 5).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler oh yes, Im new user to this forum

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent someone from deleting a file?

Comment: Yes, would you like to tell me how to do that based on my above question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason why I do to ask is that, I anticipate if someday the attacker had already physical access to the machine, the anti-deletion by using dependent OS API will not work (for example, by using a very fast booting OS like Backtrack 5).

Sorry, it an attacker can boot a different operating system there's nothing you can do, because any anti-deletion code you may have written won't be running.

This unless you manage to intercept and patch somehow the calls to the ATA/SCSI controller and insert this patch before the BIOS gives control to the OS, but I don't think that's even possible; on the other hand, physical access = root access, the attacker could as well grab a screwdriver, open the case, connect the disk to another computer and do whatever he wants with it.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix and its variants, the standard system call to remove a file is [`unlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html).  To prevent data deletion, you would have to ensure that every call to that system call, anywhere in any program run by the system, does whatever alternative trickery you want.  That is hard to do at the program level; you'd have to provide a modified C library, and you'd still find some people have worked their way around even that (they wrote some assembler, for example).  So, you might do it by modifying the behaviour of the `unlink()` system call in the kernel, but that's hard and non-portable too.

On Windows, the same comment applies to `unlink()`, but the chances are high that there are a number of other interfaces that also provide a mechanism for deleting a file.  The same arguments apply, but you'd have to trap more system calls, etc.

Finally, if you need any further nails in the coffin, the `unlink()` system call isn't the only way to destroy data.  You can open a file and truncate it, and then close it.  The file exists, but the data doesn't.  You can open a file and modify it; the file exists, but the original data is lost.

So, I think you are in for a difficult time.

You asked in first a comment and then a revision to the question:

> [If] the attacker had already physical access to the machine, the anti-deletion by using dependent OS API will not work (for example, by using a very fast booting OS like Backtrack 5).

I responded:

- If the attacker can boot to a different OS, the game is over — you can't stop the other OS from deleting the files in your current OS.

Old and ugly the words may be, but they are fundamentally true.  The OS is in charge of the raw hardware.  If the attacker gets to choose what is in charge of the hardware, the attacker wins.

See also:

- [The Ten Immutable Laws of Software Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc722487.aspx)

  1. Law #1: If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your computer, it's not your computer anymore
  2. Law #2: If a bad guy can alter the operating system on your computer, it's not your computer anymore
  3. Law #3: If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore
  4. Law #4: If you allow a bad guy to upload programs to your website, it's not your website any more
  5. Law #5: Weak passwords trump strong security
  6. Law #6: A computer is only as secure as the administrator is trustworthy
  7. Law #7: Encrypted data is only as secure as the decryption key
  8. Law #8: An out of date virus scanner is only marginally better than no virus scanner at all
  9. Law #9: Absolute anonymity isn't practical, in real life or on the Web
  10. Law #10: Technology is not a panacea

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, basically IO *is* operating system. It's the most important operating system's job to provide IO. And the C standard defines so little about it that it's gotta be different, especially when it comes to such an obscure thing as undeleting files.

You might find some library which hides the OS-specific things behind a nice API, but it's still OS dependent on how it performs that action.

Comment: I just want to anticipating that if the attacker had already access physically to the machine, and he can to boot the machine on different os, so the OS dependent anti deletion API just now will not work

Comment: @user1309539: if the attacker can boot to a different OS, the game is over - you can't stop the other OS from deleting the files in your current OS.

Comment: huh, that very old and ugly words "the game is over".

Comment: @user1309539: It an attacker had physical access to your machine you might as well flatten it and reinstall from backups.